# What's causing large artifacts in some of my digital pictures?

Tags: canon-7d, data-corruption

I took several hundred images recently, which downloaded OK apart from about a dozen that got corrupted.  I was using simultaneous RAW/JPEG on a sunny day with my Canon 7D Mark II.  Can anyone help diagnose the problem and recommend a solution please? The affected images were chopped in half and reversed in shot, exaggerated colours and sometimes included block colour. Images included these below:
[image]

I've checked and the dodgy images are all RAW.

Comment: Does the error exist in both the RAW and JPEG copies of the same image?

Comment: Did you compare the image on your disk with the images in the SD/CF card?

Comment: Also, how do you "download"? Connect the camera with a cable? Or extract CF/SD card and plug it in your PC?

Comment: Thanks folks.  Firstly, thanks Philip.  I've checked and the dodgy images are all RAW.  Xenoid - thanks, a strange thing happened in that the images on the camera disappeared  when downloaded - hasn't happened since.  So I can't remember if images looked wrong on the camera as well as downloaded.  Sorry!  And to download I connect a cable, yes.  Hope this helps.  I have more error images, but they're also basically like the ones above...

Comment: @Adrian it is likely much faster to move the card to your PC and do a file copy there (directly, or using a photo manager). This won't hurt your card, in fact this may help you to detect problems sooner. It also gives you the habit of using several cards, spreading the wear. Flash storage (SD or CF) wears out and should be replaced before it fails, ideally.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As this occurred only to the RAW files and not the JPEG copies of the same photo, that means by far the most likely explanation of the error is that your SD card is giving up. Throw it away, get a new one - it's just not worth the risk in using it again for what is a (relatively) disposable bit of kit.

In terms of recovery, you're almost certainly not going to be able to recover anything from the corrupted RAW files but you obviously have the JPEGs of the same.

Comment: Hi Philip. I've just checked again and found that actually both RAW and JPEG photos can be corrupted - but not of the same photo. Sometimes the RAW is corrupted and the JPEG is fine, but with other photos the JPEG is corrupted and the RAW is fine. Is it still most likely the SD card? Thanks.

Comment: Even more so it that case. You've got some bad blocks on your SD card and whatever gets written to those gets corrupted.

Comment: All help gratefully received, thank you.  Now taking lots of shots with new SD and CF card to check for a repeat but all good so far.  Much appreciated.